# How to get reference to SVG (child) elements nested in another SVG element (parent) using D3?

Tags: svg, d3.js, nested, parent-child

I have several groups (SVG G elements) nested in another group and I would like to get their ID's. I used the D3 javascript library to create the SVG and the code looks similar to this.

```
var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.append("svg")
    .attr("width", '100%')
    .attr("height", '100%')

var outerG = svg.append("g")
    .attr('id','outerG')

var innerG1 = outerG.append('g')
    .attr('id','innerG1')

var innerG2 = outerG.append('g')
    .attr('id','innerG2')
```

I tried to use *childNodes* attribute, but *console.log(outerG[0].childNodes)* gives me undefined. Could not find the right answer searching with google, could please someone give me a hint how to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
console.log(outerG[0][0].childNodes);
```

See [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/M7dET/)

The reason you need two nested indices is that all selections are grouped implicitly.  If you'd like to know the deeper reasons for this, or want to understand selections better in general, see [this article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day! I wonder if it is possible to get the ID's of the child-elements in a direct way, instead of looping through the resulting array of the nested elements.